How to specify shell arguments for non windows shells/terminal profiles
I am developing a vscode extension. In the extension I have a terminal profile as well as the ability to start a command in a shell, both with the appropriate environment variables I require.
One of the environment variables is "VIRTUAL_ENV" which is use to automatically run python in that virtual environment. This works for powershell and bash but not for zsh. For the zsh shell the command source venv/bin/activate must be given.
How do you pass the command as a shell argument for both registering a terminal profile and for running a custom command.
This is what my registering a terminal profile command looks like:
   context.subscriptions.push(vscode.window.registerTerminalProfileProvider('zephyr-ide.terminal-profile', {
    provideTerminalProfile(token: vscode.CancellationToken): vscode.ProviderResult<vscode.TerminalProfile> {
      let opts: vscode.TerminalOptions = {
        name: "Zephyr IDE Terminal",
        env: getShellEnvironment(wsConfig.activeSetupState, true),
      };
      return new vscode.TerminalProfile(opts);
    }
  }));

And this is how I create a new shell:
   let options: vscode.ShellExecutionOptions = {
    env: <{ [key: string]: string }>envPath,
    cwd: cwd,
  };

  let exec = new vscode.ShellExecution(cmd, options);

  // Task
  let task = new vscode.Task(
    { type: "zephyr-ide:" + taskName, command: taskName },
    vscode.TaskScope.Workspace,
    taskName,
    "zephyr-ide",
    exec
  );
  
  const execution = await vscode.tasks.executeTask(task);

U

sing shellArgs in the TerminalOptions/ShellExecutionOptions does not work. There is a note that it is only available on windows and the main use case is for osx installations.
In addition I tried setting the argument in the settings.json file, but that will either cause the terminal profile to create a terminal that doesn't stay open or causes me to execute a command that does not complete execution.
export function setZshArg(platform_name: string, as_terminal_profile: boolean) {
    let zsh_argument = ["-c", "source " + path.join(python_venv_location, "bin", "activate") + (as_terminal_profile ? "; zsh -i" : "")]
    const configuration = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration();
    let terminal_profile_name = "terminal.integrated.profiles." + platform_name;
    let terminal_profile: any = configuration.get(terminal_profile_name);
    if (Object.keys(terminal_profile)[0] === "zsh" || configuration.get('terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.' + platform_name) == "zsh") {
        terminal_profile.zsh.args = zsh_argument;
        configuration.update(terminal_profile_name, terminal_profile);
    }
}

I would also like to be able to determine what is the default shell that vscode will use so that the injection can occur only when the underlying shell is zsh.
